# Include thredded in my application page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a rails application. On my page, I have 3 tabs. I want to include thredded in my application page so that it can come on my third tab. 
For now it is running as a standalone application. 
What can be done to make it a part of tab.

I have mounted this line in routes.rb :

```
mount Thredded::Engine => '/forum'
```

I am not getting what to do to include it in my tab section.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the third tab in your application's layout to link to the thredded forum you've mounted into your app?

If so, the third tab should link to `/forum`. `<a href="/forum">Forum</a>`

If I'm misunderstanding the problem can you expand a little bit more about what the actual issue is?

Comment: Acc to you, that will have a word forum and clicking that word, my forum will open as a standalone. but i want that in tab only.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by "tab only"

Comment: there are 3 tab panel in my page. So in one tab i want to have that thredded